# Apex record owner able to delete the record

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

VF PAGE:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="deletecontact">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock > 

<m>Please make sure that you have removed links to this contact's tasks or that you have linked the existing tasks of this contact to another contact </m>
<br/>
<m> Veuillez vous assurer que vous avez supprimé les liens de tâches à ce contact ou que vous avez lié les tâches de ce contact à un autre contact</m>

<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"  oncomplete="redirectBack()"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Continue" action="{!dodelete}" />
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public class deletecontact {
private final Contact con; 
    public deletecontact(ApexPages.StandardController standardPageController) {
        this.con = (contact)standardPageController.getRecord(); 
    }

    //method called from the Visualforce's action attribute
    public PageReference dodelete() {
        List<contact> contactToDelete1 =[select createdbyid,ownerid from contact where ownerid=:userinfo.getuserid()];   
        contact contactToDelete = new contact(Id = con.Id); 
        contactToDelete1.add(contactToDelete); 
        if ((!contactToDelete1.isEmpty()){        
            Contacttodelete.adderror('This contact cannot be Deleted. please contact the Administration Department. Thank you.');           

            delete contactToDelete1;
        }
        PageReference pageWhereWeEndUp = new PageReference('https://cs6.salesforce.com/003/o'); //set the return page reference to the Opportunity tab
        return pageWhereWeEndUp.setRedirect(true); //send the User on their way
    }
}
```

i am getting how can i do only record owner can able to delete his record not others .

in this it is delete other records also how can i proceed ?

Comment: it working in this way that any user can delete all otheruser records

Comment: i need that only the record owner can be able to delete only his record

Comment: You can implement using profile permission. Remove profile permission of "Edit All" so that only user will be able to delete his own records and not of others

Comment: @user4045 Some feedbacks on your code here .In page-reference method i see hardcoded URL.Please be relative as it may break once promoted to production.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the user's profile doesn't have the permission "Modify All" either on the object or under system permissions.

As an additional step, make sure your OWD settings and sharing rules  are correct on that object and your are using the WITH SHARING keyword, this wouldn't solve the issue itself but it would prevent users getting access to records they should not view.